# First cell in DataGrid doesn't get selected in the DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

When the user presses "Search" (Sök) the list is populated. When the search is finished the first row is selected via the Trigger "IsEnabled", the problem is that the first cell isn't (see pic).

[image: PIC OF THE PROBLEM]

Here's my style code for the DatagridCells

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="0,4,0,4" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Transparent" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="#7dc0dc" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
              Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="#fff" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
             Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="#7dc0dc" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
              Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="#fff" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

NOTE that if the user refreshes the search the row gets selected correctly once the list is populated once more. It also gets selected correctly if the user manually clicks on the row. The error only occurs when a new search is made.

Am I missing some magic working trigger property?

Comment: Hi there.  Not related to your question but I like the theme you're using.  Are you using a third party template for that or did you develop it yourself?

Comment: Oh thx, it's my own development I'm afraid